# MacOS screencapture Entitlements for Marking up screenshots and screenshot UI

Tags: macos, screenshot, appstore-sandbox

I am writing a small MacOS app that hooks into the ability to make screenshots.

I am leveraging screencapture to take the screenshots but I am running into some issues with running the app in sandbox mode.

I already found that I needed to add the entitlement

```
key: com.apple.security.temporary-exception.mach-register.global-name 
value: com.apple.screencapture.interactive
```

To be able to run screencapture in interactive mode (screencapture -i), to select screenshots of a specific size.

However, I can't find the entitlements I need to display the screenshot HUD (screencapture -U)(the HUD you get when you click cmd+shift+5) or the markup screenshot window (screencapture -u) (the little popup window after you take a screenshot so you can mark it up).

Does anyone know which entitlements to use or if Apple has some index over entitlements and their usage?